# bug in guess number game

Tags: python, python-3.x

there is my code:

```
answer = input("Player 1 , Please enter your number: (1 - 100) \n") 
answer = int(answer)
is_correct = False
count = 0
while count < 10 and is_correct == False:
    guess = int(input("Player 2 Please enter you guees: \n"))
    count = count + 1
    if guess == answer:
        print("Player 2 You won!")
        is_correct = True
    elif guess < answer:
        print("Player 2 your number is smaller thean the answer !")
    elif guess > answer:
        print("Player 2 your number is greater than the answer !")

if is_correct == False:
    print("Player 2 You Lost :(")
```

hello I'm trying to write a guess number game
but there is a bug here
someone can enter a number bigger than 100 and smaller than 0
but the number should be between 0 and 100
how can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like you are not checking anywhere in your code to make sure the input is between 0 and 100.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] for tips like starting with your own research and how to write a good title.

Comment: You might also want to read [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](/q/23294658/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

Add this while loop right after the second line:

```
while answer < 1 or answer > 100:
    answer = int(input("Player 1, Please enter your number: (1 - 100) \n"))
```

This will repeat asking Player 1 until he surrenders to your demands.

Comment: I think OP wants `answer < 0`, but other than that this is the correct approach.

Comment: His code and his question are in slight conflict about that.

Comment: I see now, I'm on my phone and the rest of the question was offscreen. `< 1` is correct :)